# Map Database Design

Tags: database-design

I am creating an app for my final year project. It involves finding the shortest path in case of a disaster. How do I start constructing the database of my map? Any advice will be really appreciate.Thanks

Comment: Could you please elaborate?

Comment: You will probably want to base this on a real map, so look at OpenStreetMap, Google Maps and Bing Maps (etc). You'll probably want to plot markers on a map, so look at Leaflet.js (although there may be more more maintained alternatives now).

Comment: @manetsus My advisor said that I should start by searching best routing algorithms, I'm already working on that. The next step is to integrate a map in my app. The app will show your current location and the next safest place out of the boundary of disaster. I needed some help on designing the map database of my area. how do I go about this.

Answer (score 0):

There are probably lots of ways to do this.  But one way might be to visualize your space as a grid, where each square in the grid is a location in your "map".  A grid is easily represented as a matrix.

You might find something like this helpful?
http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/multidimensional-arrays.html?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com

Good luck with your project!